How to restrict an IIS 10.0 website to get access to all paths except the website itself?
I created a .Net8 website in IIS called TestWeb. The directory where the website is located is "D:\websites\TestWeb".
I found out that the user of this website process is IIS APPPOOL\TestWeb. This WebSite can read any file on the machine, and can create files anywhere on the machine.
How to restrict this website or user (IIS APPPOOL\TestWeb) from accessing files and folders on other paths, such as C:\Windows\ or E:\MyFiles? What should I do?
My system is Windows Server 2016, IIS 10.0.14393.0.
Thanks very much !

there should be a site object that restricts where its being read and avoid relative path traversal. also that pool user has too much permission. restrict that first

First you could manually remove or set to deny the iis app pool user from the all folder permission list where you think it is not needed.
Then you can make sure iis site app pool and site is set to the iis app pool identity as shown below:


You could use iis url rewrite rule to restrict the access to the folder path for eg:
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/test/.*" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
                </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>

